# Recurrent Neural Network: Different numpy reshape in these two articles?

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network

The First: https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/

The above says that we have a sequence of like 96 samples, 1 time-step, and 1 feature.

The Second: https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/

The above says that we have a sequence of 1 sample, many time-steps, and 1 feature.

What is the difference? E.g., if I measure temperature and pressure every day for 30 days then I assume it's 30 samples and 2 features. Then is time-step how many days ahead I'll want to predict? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Further, the input_shape is different between the two. Is this the difference between feeding one observation at a time vs the entire dataset?

Answer (score 0):

*What is the difference? E.g., if I measure temperature and pressure every day for 30 days then I assume it's 30 samples and 2 features. Then is time-step how many days ahead I'll want to predict?*

The time-step is how many past days worth of data to be used to build the model.

If past 29 days data is used to build the model, input data shape is

(1, 29, 2) => sample - 1, time-steps - 30, features - 2.

If past 28 days data is used, input data shape is

(2, 28, 2) => sample - 2, time-steps - 29, features - 2.

And so on...